# How to control axis labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I am trying to visualize some data as a scatter plot with matplotlib, and I got the following:
[image]

Is there a way to force the y axis to show the following steps [0,10,100,1000,10000,...]
Similar to the following:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean `y-axis` in `log-scale` ?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to set the `yscale()` to 'log' and I got really nice result:[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are directly working with `matplotlib` and if you are more familiar with the new-style format string, you can try this:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

plt.figure()
plt.ylim(10e1,10e6)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}')) # 2 decimal places
plt.grid()
```

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html):

> **class matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)**
>
> Use a new-style format string (as used by str.format()) to format the
> tick.
>
> The field used for the value must be labeled x and the field used for
> the position must be labeled pos.

**Output Image:**

[image: OutputImage]